# Floated form having mystery top offset

Tags: html, css

I am having an odd problem where a form is having about 1px of margin on the top of it, and I cannot find why. I was also not able to recreate this situation in jsbin, so I am not sure what could be causing it.

Here is an image of what is happening:
[image: Weird margins]

Chrome litterally says nothing about margins,padding or borders causing this problem. The form is inside a list item just like the correctly formatted link to the left. Upon further inspection, ie actually does say it has 2px of "offset" on the top of it, but again no indication to why it exists.

Heres some HTML from the problem (note, a lot of this stuff is actually on one line because of previous problems with inline-block):

```
<div id="headcontainer">
    <div id="headcenter">
        <header class="left">A header</header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="left">
                Some other list stuff
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li>
                    <form id="loginform">
                        <input id="usernamein" type="text">
                        <input id="passwordin" type="password">
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS (entire document has a html5 css reset):

```
label,input{font-family:"Arial Rounded MT Bold","Helvetica Rounded",Arial,sans-serif}
input{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;display:inline-block}

.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
.clear{clear:both}

#headcontainer{position:fixed;z-index:100;height:30px;width:100%;top:0;background-color:#1c1c1c;border-bottom:3px solid #cc3f33}
#headcenter{max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto}
#headcenter header{padding:5px;margin:0 10 0 0px}
#headcenter nav{height:30px}
#headcenter ul{list-style:none;height:inherit}
#headcenter li{display:inline-block;height:inherit}
#headcenter li a{height:23px;padding:7px 4px 0;border-bottom:3px solid #cc3f33}

#loginform{display:inline-block;width:200px;height:30px}
#usernamein,#passwordin{width:50%;height:100%}
```

I was actually able to fix the problem by changing `input{display:inline-block}` to `input{display:block}`, but this causes the inputs to not be aligned how I want them. I do not understand why changing the display even causes this problem. Any explanation/fix to this would be helpful (not something like `top:-2px`).

Comment: This will give you the idea on what is happening: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @gp. As I said on that one answer, I don't think this is the problem as all of the stuff between ul tags is on one line. Just to try I got rid of all tabs in the document and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` observes white space (e.g. new lines (\n), et cetera)

So unless your closing tags are on the same line as your opening tags, you will end up with "random white space" when using inline-block. E.g. ......

There is a "technical" answer which you can research if you choose...

Comment: I just spaced out the code for readability. I previously had this problem with the list elements and everything between the ul tags is on one line.

Comment: just for kicks: try this: <form><input ... /><input ... /></form>

Comment: Yea that didn't fix it, that's only necessary in xhtml anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your markup to the max! Also, you could eliminate `inline-block` (personally I never seem to use it)

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/63tqY/)

HTML

```
<header>
<nav> 
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
    <form id="loginform"> 
        <a href="#">Login</a>
        <input id="usernamein" type="text" />
        <input id="passwordin" type="password" />
    </form>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:"Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
}
input {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    height:23px;
    float: left;
}
header {
    height:30px;
    background:#1c1c1c;
    border-bottom:3px solid #cc3f33;
}
header nav form {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
}
header nav form a {
    margin: 0 10px 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: I actually figured out that I could make the link in the second ul have a left float, and make the form have a right one. That magically seemed to fix everything but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: No worries, it does seem that the list items are not needed though.